# Display images in grid view in windows phone 8

Tags: gridview, windows-phone-8

I'm getting the images from server. 
I don't know how many number of images come from server when i request for images.
After getting the images i want to display them in Grid View with 3 columns for each row
as shown in the below figure. So here the columns are fixed (3). The rows should be changed based on the number of images.

[image]

Could you please tell me how to do that in windows phone 8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility could be to use a LongListSelector and set the LayoutMode to Grid.

Then you would set the GridCellSize in such a way that only 3 images show up per row (ex. If the screen has width 480 set GridCellSize to 160x160 for 3 square images on each row.)

Answer (score 4):

Create a simple Listbox and set its ItemsPanel to `toolkit:WrapPanel` with `Orientation="Horizontal"`

```
<ListBox Margin="0,40,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="450" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid Height="150" Width="150">
            <Image Height="130" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Just on a note, if too many images are loaded on the view all together, it may lead to Out Of Memory exception. So just make sure the images you are adding are thumbnails and not complete images. VirtualizationStackPanel may slightly improve the performance.

Comment: Using this approach the items are not being virtualized, and you could end up with an OutOfMemoryException.

Answer (score 2):

If your purpose is to display images only (not selection) then go for `ItemsControl`, check out below code.

XAML

```xml
<ItemsControl x:Name="ic">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Stretch="None" Source="{Binding First}" />
                <Image Stretch="None" Source="{Binding Second}" Grid.Column="1" />
                <Image Stretch="None" Source="{Binding Third}" Grid.Column="2" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

C#

```csharp
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var URLs = new List<Uri> 
    {
        new Uri("http://i.imgur.com/SG8KZCh.png"),
        new Uri("http://i.imgur.com/SG8KZCh.png"),
        new Uri("http://i.imgur.com/SG8KZCh.png"),
        new Uri("http://i.imgur.com/SG8KZCh.png"),
        new Uri("http://i.imgur.com/SG8KZCh.png"),
        new Uri("http://i.imgur.com/SG8KZCh.png"),
        new Uri("http://i.imgur.com/SG8KZCh.png"),
        new Uri("http://i.imgur.com/SG8KZCh.png"),
        new Uri("http://i.imgur.com/SG8KZCh.png"),
        new Uri("http://i.imgur.com/SG8KZCh.png"),
        new Uri("http://i.imgur.com/SG8KZCh.png")
    };

    var GroupedURLs = new List<ImageViewModel>();
    for (int i = 0; i < URLs.Count; i=i+3)
    {
        var objImageViewModel = new ImageViewModel();
        if (URLs.ElementAtOrDefault(i) != null)
        {
            objImageViewModel.First = URLs[i];
        }
        if (URLs.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1) != null)
        {
            objImageViewModel.Second = URLs[i + 1];
        }
        if (URLs.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 2) != null)
        {
            objImageViewModel.Third = URLs[i + 2];
        }

        GroupedURLs.Add(objImageViewModel);
    }

    ic.ItemsSource = GroupedURLs;
}

public class ImageViewModel
{
    public Uri First { get; set; }
    public Uri Second { get; set; }
    public Uri Third { get; set; }
}
```